# Is JavaFX capable of using Node templates?

Tags: graphics, javafx

I'm currently working on a tool which requires to display a large number of nodes (here ImageView) on a canvas pane. Most of them will contain the very same image. In order to save resources I want to avoid adding the ImageView multiple times to the scene graph. Is there a way to render the ImageView on different positions within my canvas at the same time?

Game frameworks usually use such a technique. I think it's called templating. Is there something similar in JavaFX?

Comment: Are you using a `Canvas` or a `Pane`? You can't add an `ImageView` to a `Canvas`. You cannot add the same `ImageView` (or any other node) multiple times to the scene graph, but you can reuse the same `Image` in multiple `ImageView`s.

Comment: The point is, that I don't want to add the node multiple times to the scene graph but tell the engine to render the same instance multiple times using a different translation each time. Meanwhile I'll figured that I can draw images directly on the canvas which is sufficient for my use case. Just asked the question out of curiousity.